# MYSQL sum a colum and select the individual row that were summed

Tags: mysql

Hey All you out there,

I am trying to write a query that sums the amount of data members of a group are allowed to use, and also in that same query select the amount of data an individual member is allowed to use.

This is my query at the moment

```
SELECT (groups.extra_space + DataPlan.total_disk_space_limit) AS total_space, 
   SUM(User.disk_space_limit) AS total_allocated, 
   User.id, User.first_name, 
   User.last_name, 
   User.disk_space_limit 
FROM groups INNER JOIN users AS User ON (groups.id = User.group_id)
INNER JOIN data_plans AS DataPlan    ON (groups.data_plan_id = DataPlan.id 
AND User.group_id = Group_id) WHERE groups.id = 24;
```

The data set this returns is:

```
+-------------+-----------------+----+------------+-----------+------------------+
| total_space | total_allocated | id | first_name | last_name | disk_space_limit |
+-------------+-----------------+----+------------+-----------+------------------+
|         300 |              82 | 22 | Big        | Bird      |                0 |
+-------------+-----------------+----+------------+-----------+------------------+
```

I would like the data set to be more along the lines of...

```
+-------------+-----------------+----+------------+-----------+------------------+
| total_space | total_allocated | id | first_name | last_name | disk_space_limit |
+-------------+-----------------+----+------------+-----------+------------------+
|         300 |              82 | 22 | Big        | Bird      |                0 |
|         300 |              82 | 23 | Cookie     | Monster   |               11 |
|         300 |              82 | 24 | Oscar      | Grouch    |               32 |
|         300 |              82 | 25 | Count      | Count     |               19 |
|         300 |              82 | 26 | Snuffel    | Ufogus    |               20 |
+-------------+-----------------+----+------------+-----------+------------------+
```

I know this would be easy to do in 2 queries, but I would really like to learn how to do it in one.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just add a `group by User.id` clause to the end of of your current query

Edit: Here is an example with a subquery:

```
SELECT (groups.extra_space + DataPlan.total_disk_space_limit) AS total_space, 
   (select SUM(users.disk_space_limit) from users WHERE users.group_id = groups.id) AS total_allocated, 
   User.id, User.first_name, 
   User.last_name, 
   User.disk_space_limit 
FROM groups INNER JOIN users AS User ON (groups.id = User.group_id)
INNER JOIN data_plans AS DataPlan    ON (groups.data_plan_id = DataPlan.id 
AND User.group_id = Group_id) WHERE groups.id = 24;
```

Comment: That gets halfway there.... it returns  all of the users but the total_allocated is the same as disk_space_limit in each row returned

Comment: So total_allocated is for all users?

Comment: yeah, total_allocated should be the sum of all the users disk_space_limit. So in this case 82

Comment: Hmm, I think you may need to use a subquery to get the total_allocated. I can't think of what that would be off the top of my head though.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer so the diskspace is summed up in the a subquery

Comment: MYSQL does not like it, it says that the "Subquery returns more than 1 row", which is strange to me.

Comment: Wait wait wait... I changed the subquery to this (select SUM(users.disk_space_limit) from users WHERE users.group_id = groups.id) AS total_allocated

Thank you! I will update your answer and mark it correct! Life saver!